# Cucumber Excel Data Read

Tags: excel, cucumber, sample

I have created cucumber framework. I have 60 fields in my future file and it is very difficult for me to enter the data. Is there any possibility to load the data from excel in cucumber framework. Any sample Code is available?

Comment: Please include your feature file in the question.

Comment: Please state what language you are using with Cucumber, Ruby, JS, Jave etc.

Comment: If you are using Java, you can use Apache POI to read the data from the excel. That said, do you really need to test on each of those 60 fields? Or are some tests regarding some fields and other tests regarding other fields? You might want to look into using Builder pattern to build objects (with default values) and/or splitting your scenarios.

Comment: @diabolist- Java

Comment: @Marit -Need to test all the 60 fiel

Comment: You could DataTables in Cucumber, or implement Apache POI to read from Excel. In the latter case, I'm not so sure about the added value of Cucumber...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using rest data through CSV file in Cucumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49931075/using-rest-data-through-csv-file-in-cucumber)