# Using rest data through CSV file in Cucumber

Tags: cucumber

I want to upload test data through a CSV file instead of using a feature file in cucumber. Is there any way to upload CSV in feature file for test data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to replace a feature file with a csv file in Cucumber. You need to read the csv file from your steps.

If you are on Java, Apache POI may one option.